# So I have a jquery selector and I am chaining many methods as well as using a toggle

Tags: jquery, methods, toggle, chaining

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("header").css({
        "background-color":"#93E9BE",
        "color": "white",
        "text-align": "center",
        "font-size" : "xx-large"
    }).click(function(){
        $(this).toggle(function(){
            $(this).css("background-color","red");
        }, function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "black");
        }),
       
    })
    
});
```

Comment: What is the question or problem?

Comment: Sorry I am new here and the format kind of confused me at first and didnt meant to send as such but its basically what I am working on, (I wanted to repost but now I see you have to wait).  So I cannot get the toggle () to toggle between red and black backgrounds. I fixed my curly braces situation if that is someone that will be discussed but I am just trying to see if I can chain all of this in stead of creating a class in css and to how far I can do with this  "style"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.toggle()` is used to *display or hide the matched elements*. So to just toggle the background, you can try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var initial = 'rgb(147, 233, 190)';
    var red     = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
    var black   = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';

    $("header").css({
        "background-color": initial,
        "color": "white",
        "text-align": "center",
        "font-size" : "xx-large"
    }).click(function(){
        if( $(this).css('background-color') === initial ){
            $(this).css('background-color', red);
        }else if( $(this).css('background-color') === red ){
            $(this).css('background-color', black);
        }else{
            $(this).css("background-color", initial);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header style="height:50px;"></header>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! and I was unaware that toggle was for hiding or display!

Comment: after toying around with it (sorry for so much questions) I thought I could add an else if to possibly toggle back to the color I had originally put or have just complicated this process?

Comment: So you mean something like: if it's black, it should change to red, if it's red, it should change to _"back to the color I had originally" and so on?

Comment: yes back to the original color sir!

Comment: I went ahead and marked it solved because I don't know what I am doing and I am sure I am wording this stuff very poorly haha!

Comment: I've updated my answer to cater for the _"if else"_ kindly check it out.

Comment: Man thats great! Is there anything you need?